# Use of indefinite article before "worsening"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, countability

Since worsening is an uncountable, singular noun according to the Cambridge dictionary, I dont know how an indefinite article comes before it. For example:

" No one could have predicted such a dramatic worsening of the economy."

I am having a hard time as to when to use an indefinite article before an uncountable noun or when to know a word is countable or not.

Answer (score 1):

The labeling on the Cambridge dictionary website is slightly confusing. Looking at [the definition for *worsening*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/worsening), we see it is labeled "U or S".

- "U" means "Uncountable or singular noun: a noun that has no plural." I think it's saying that if a noun is uncountable, it **must** be singular. This is true. There is no such thing as a plural uncountable.

  - WRONG: "Let's listen to some *musics*."
  - RIGHT: "Let's listen to some *music*."
  - WRONG: "I ate a bowl of *rices*."
  - RIGHT: "I ate a bowl of *rice*."
- "S" means "A singular noun." There are no additional details.

In other words, "U or S" means that *worsening* can be used as an uncountable (and therefore singular) noun, **or** as a "plain" singular noun.

In your example sentence, *worsening* is **not** an uncountable noun. The author is referring to a single, particular instance of the economy getting worse. Its count is one. This is why it is correct to use an indefinite article. You could also use a definite article. ("The dramatic worsening of the economy caught everyone by surprise.")

---

More generally, many nouns can shift back and forth between being uncountable and being countable, depending on the context. For example, I could speak of "the rices of China" if I was talking about different breeds or varieties of rice.

For more detail, see some of these other questions:

- [Does an uncountable noun take an article if it has an adjective before it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16694/46857)
- [Using indefinite articles before adjectives: "Let's have a good breakfast"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/80429/46857)
- [The article “a/an” with uncountable nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43757/208972) (English Language & Usage SE)