# Article "a" with uncountable nouns

Tags: articles

There is such a thing in English that when a mass noun combined with an adjective it takes the indefinite article. For example:

> He had **a great knowledge** of English.

But I have noticed that is not always the case. For example: I have observed that with the word "fluency" and other adjective the is not followed, for instance:

> She showed **great fluency** in English.

Would it be correct to say "She showed a great fluency in English"? Tell me please if there is any additional rule to that.

Comment: Hmmm...no. _He had a great courage_ is not correct.

Comment: Some non-count nouns can take the indefinite article, but I don't think "courage" does. "Fluency" can in _There was a noticeable **fluency** in the way he spoke_. There are a very few non-count nouns where "a" can combine with a non-count singular noun, for example _Ed has a good **knowledge** of Latin_; _We wasted a great **deal** of time_; _A **number** of problems have arisen_; _I have a high **regard** for them_, and one or two others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does an uncountable noun take an article if it has an adjective before it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/does-an-uncountable-noun-take-an-article-if-it-has-an-adjective-before-it)

Comment: Michael Swan: With certain uncountable nouns - especially nouns referring to human emotions and mental activity - we often use a/an when we are limiting their meaning in some way. 
_We need a secretary with a first-class knowledge of German. (NOT ... with first-class knowledge of German.)_
Note that these nouns cannot normally be used in the plural, and that **most uncountable nouns cannot be used with a/an at all, even when they have an adjective.**
_My father enjoys very good health. (NOT ... a very good health)
He speaks excellent English. (NOT ... an excellent English.)_

Comment: I think Laurel is correct; I think [hunter's answer there](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16697/16251) about converting mass nouns to counting may be what is going on here. It's not that the adjective directly causes the change, but the adjective signals that there is a (possibly unstated) comparison happening, which converts what appears to be a mass noun to a countable. If "she shows a great fluency in English", that fluency must be great in comparison to something else--either her fluency in another language, or other people's fluency in English.

Comment: @BillJ I think instead of fluency you could also say courage: *There was a noticeable **courage** in the way he spoke.*  But the context is different than in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a rule in Michael Swan's "Practical English Usage" (section 149.4):

> With certain uncountable nouns – especially nouns referring to human
>   emotions and mental activity – we often use a/an when we are limiting
>   their meaning in some way (and we generally limit it by putting
>   adjectives).
>
> - We need a secretary with a first-class knowledge of German (NOT...with first class knowledge of German ).
> - She has always had a deep distrust of strangers.
> - That child shows a surprising understanding of adult behaviour.
> - My parents wanted me to have a good education (NOT .... to have good  education).
> - You've been a great help.
> - I need a good sleep.
>
> Note that these nouns cannot normally be used in the plural, and that
>   most uncountable nouns cannot be used with a/an at all, even when they
>   have an adjective.
>
> - My father enjoys very good health. (NOT ... a very good health.)
> - We are having terrible weather. (NOT... a terrible weather.)
> - He speaks excellent English. (NOT ... an excellent English.)
> - It's interesting work (NOT ... an interesting work.)

Unfortunately this book does't show a list of such uncountable nouns which can/cannot be used with "a". But the Ngram Viewer shows that "fluency" is not used with "a". See the results of searching:

- [have great fluency vs. have a great fluency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20great%20fluency%2Chave%20a%20great%20fluency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20great%20fluency%3B%2Cc0) - Ngrams not found: have **a** great fluency
- [has great fluency  vs. has a great fluency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+great+fluency%2Chas+a+great+fluency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20great%20fluency%3B%2Cc0) - Ngrams not found: has **a** great fluency
- [with great fluency vs. with a great fluency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+great+fluency%2Cwith+a+great+fluency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20great%20fluency%3B%2Cc0) - Ngrams not found: with **a** great fluency

So, it would be better to say "She showed great fluency in English".