# "to have a perfect hearing" - is the article acceptable?

Tags: articles

"You have a perfect hearing" or "You have perfect hearing".
Which one is correct? I have seen both versions and I am wondering if the first one is OK. By ”hearing" I mean "the ability to hear".

If I understand correctly, uncountable nouns should not be preceded by the indefinite article unless the meaning is particular, not general, e.g. "I had a good education". Is that the case here?

I know my question refers to the use of articles with uncountable nouns. I have found a similar question but I am still not sure.

[Article “a” with uncountable nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139210/article-a-with-uncountable-nouns)

Comment: I am surprised you have seen “a perfect hearing”. It is not grammatical to use *a* with *hearing*. Unless you mean a sense of hearing besides “the ability to perceive sound”, like a Congressional hearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hearing* meaning one of your five (or so) senses, is not a count noun, so you can't have "a hearing".

When we hear "a hearing" we think of legal procedures or formal administrative meetings, since that sense of *hearing* is a count noun.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds awkward to say as a native English speaker. If you were to say "I had a perfect hearing", I think most would assume you were talking about a legal hearing/congressional hearing, not hearing sound.

This is one of those cases where there are a lot of exceptions to a rule and you just have to learn them case by case as far as I know.